# How to add a label to an entity in Cesiumjs

Tags: gis, cesiumjs

How to add a label to an entity(polygon) in cesium? I tried the following code, but the label did not show. I don't know where I code it wrong

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");

var entity = viewer.entities.add({
  polygon : {
    hierarchy : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([
                              -109.080842,45.002073,
                              -105.91517,45.002073,
                              -104.058488,44.996596,
                              -104.053011,43.002989,
                              -104.053011,41.003906,
                              -105.728954,40.998429,
                              -107.919731,41.003906,
                              -109.04798,40.998429,
                              -111.047063,40.998429,
                              -111.047063,42.000709,
                              -111.047063,44.476286,
                              -111.05254,45.002073]),
    height : 0,
    material : Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5),
    outline : true,
    outlineColor : Cesium.Color.BLACK
  },
  label: {text: 'hello world'}
});

entity.label.show = true;
viewer.zoomTo(entity);
```

[image: WX20200508-152835@2x.png]

You can test it in the demo code on the official website: https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html?src=GeoJSON%20and%20TopoJSON.html&label=DataSources

Answer (score 2):

Unlike a polygon, a label depends on the Entity having a `position`.  The label is shown at (or relative to) the Entity's position.

Try adding this line to your sample code:

```
position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-108, 43),
```

Here's the [complete demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html#c=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).